# Synonym / Alternate expression for "for fear that"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, prepositional-phrases

Can anyone help me out here? It's been nagging me all afternoon, scrounging around in my head for it and plumbing the Web--I swear I've heard a more literary alternative for this one before.

I'm looking for a synonym or different expression for *"for fear that"*.

Something like "God forbid" comes to mind, but that's not quite it: too idiomatic. Though it has a completely different meaning, "by dint of" keeps presenting itself I think because the one that's eluding me is also a prepositional phrase, maybe three words.

Answer (score 4):

## [Lest](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lest)

> for fear that —often used after an expression denoting fear or
>   apprehension
>
> worried lest she should be late
>
> hesitant to speak out lest he be fired

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice for the question to have an exact sentence as there is a difference between doing something FOR the purpose of avoiding trouble vs doing something with reservations that it might go wrong?

Might go wrong but doing it anyway:

- with trepidation

Did something a bit differently to reduce risk

- *due to uncertainty*
- *out of saftey concerns*
- *at the risk of* rain delay, we had contigency plans